# Graphics artifacts in form's event VB6

Tags: forms, vb6

i've a problem when switching form, basically i see some artifacts for a couple of seconds when i do something like form2.show

This image is a snapshot of what i'm saying :

[image: Example]

What is the right way for loading forms one over the other ?

Comment: Temporarily comment out the code in Form2's Form_Load event, or whatever other event takes a long time to run when starting up Form2. Does the problem go away?

Comment: first load the form without making it visible, when the loading is complete, show it .... can you post your form_load and form_resize and form_active and form_paint codes?

Comment: I load everything in my form_load, i don't use form resize and form_active. I tried to comment out all if  the code in my form_load but this still happens. I found out that if i set the form visibility to false than i set it to true at the end of the form_load the artifacts are less and very quick.